# How to access data on an external ssd drive with MBR only?

Tags: linux, partitioning, ssd, data-recovery

My old laptop's display died, so I took its SSD and connected it to another laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 externally via USB using M2 SSD case. There should be two operating systems: Windows and Ubuntu on the SSD. I'd like to get some data from Ubuntu's disk part, but OS can't see its data.

[Disks output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIK7B.png)

```
$ sudo gdisk /dev/sda

GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Problem reading disk in BasicMBRData::ReadMBRData()!
Warning! Read error 22; strange behavior now likely!
Warning! Read error 22; strange behavior now likely!
Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. THIS OPERATION IS POTENTIALLY DESTRUCTIVE! Exit by
typing 'q' if you don't want to convert your MBR partitions
to GPT format!
***************************************************************
```

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda

fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: No such file or directory
```

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 152d:a578 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
...
```

I've tried [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/963178/how-do-i-convert-my-linux-disk-from-mbr-to-gpt-with-uefi/963179#963179), but it didn't work for me.

Comment: try with `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`

Comment: i would create a RAW image instead of manipulate a drive - use dd for that kind - moreover if it fails just use the backup yu have to revert your change

Comment: @RomeoNinov added this into the question

Comment: What's the output from `sudo lsblk`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle There is only one row about sda disk: `sda  8:0    0     0B  0 disk`

Comment: do you have a different USB->SSD adapter - I've had nothing but issues with JMicron ones (though mine is `152d:1561` so the `152d:a578` may not be hot garbage like mine)

Comment: The above notwithstanding there are too many things here that don't make sense, at all. First "old laptop" and "M2 SSD case" don 't really go together; a M.2 connector is quite current and can be used for new NVMe drives as well as older SATA drives but unlikely to be found in old laptops. Second, Google seems to think your enclosure's JMicron chipset is for mSATA? A different, older and *de facto* obsolete connector that's obviously for SATA only. Now, **could it be that your laptop was current enough to have a NVMe drive that you now inserted in a SATA only adapter?** (keep reading)

Comment: (...) This situation is indeed possible with M.2 drives as explained above. That being the case it would explain the symptom. It's actually a common situation - dozens of questions here, probably - a people who don't know better keep stumbling on this issue because both drives fit the same connector, most of the times, but unless explicitly specified as supporting both, a NVMe drive won't work in a SATA adapter or vice versa. So, **please edit the question and post the hardware you're working with, both the drive and the adapter**.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the possibilities to connect the SSD as external device to a different system:

You write the reason for the whole action is the defect display of your notebook. — Did you ever try to connect an external monitor?

Via an external display the notebook would be still usable and could continue doing its service. Or at least by this you could circumvent the problems brought through the external USB-adapter, as you can backup your data from within the regular environment.

---

Seeing the screenshot of your Disk tool it is obvious, that the USB adapter logic is accepted similar like a DVD drive. But the "inserted" media, your SSD is currently not online.

Some reasons are possible:

1. There might be a `Power ON/OFF` functionality at the adatpter.
2. The connection between the adapter and the SSD is not seated properly or is somehow connected the wrong way.
3. The adapter system requires an external power supply, especially the SSD. The adaper logic is online (as the screenshot proves) but the SSD fails because of possible lack of power.

Checking the first two possibilities should be trivial. And, as I don't know your exact model, I cannot tell useful details to look for.

Possibility No 3 is the most tricky one.

Helpful would have been to know the details of your adapter to carve out not relevant possibilities. So I stay at a more generic level:

Please note that an USB port is not necessarily equal to the USB-port just aside:

One of them can be a "USB Charger" the other one is a USB 3.0, the next one is only USB 2.0. — And these are only the most notable possibilities the of the USB-port "Type A", the large square one. — The USB-C type also differs widely in its internal capabilities.

All mentioned types in common is the problem that their USB definition of the allowed max power consumption per port differ widely. (i.e. see the [table at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#Allowable_current_draw)

So choosing the wrong port possibly will result in a failing device. You can feel lucky if a device will not show up at all when under-powered. Else the device will fail when the power consumption hits the limit. Typical this happens when trying to write somewhat more than a few bytes. — The most unsuitable moment for the safety of your data.

So check out these items:

- If there is the possibility of an external power supply, use it.
- If they supply a Y-connector cable with the adapter to connect 2 USB-A slots, connect both.
- If you have the choice to connect to a "faster" USB port, do it.
- Check your system documentation to recognize a possibly available port designated for device charging.
- Check your BIOS settings. The charging capabilities may be customizable in the BIOS.
- If you are using a notebook, use its power plug to override the power saving features when operating via battery.
- Check the power saving settings of your operating system (*"Allow charging of USB devices"* might enable higher power consumption via the USB port.)

Surely you recognize that some of these possibilities might combine. So check all of them. And surely there are some more I did not think of in this moment.